# locking partitions inside an array in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, task-parallel-library, azure-data-lake

I have basically created one byte array named buffer. Inside that i am having 5 imaginary partitions which i am accessing using counters.
i want to write to the 5 partitons inside the array parallelly and then append to a file in ADLS Gen 1 using concurrentAppend.
i used the approach below and data corruption occurs , seemingly a critical section problem.
My aim now is to lock the particular partitions( and not the whole array) to which data is written and after that release the lock affter appending.

i am using .NET SDK ( 3.0.100)

would be verry grateful to any help.

```
     Parallel.For(0,5,i=>{
             path[i] = @"C:\Users\t-chkum\Desktop\InputFiles\1MB\" + (i+1) + ".txt";

                   FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path[i]);
                   stream.Read(buffer,counter,(int)stream.Length);
                  //Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer,counter,(int)stream.Length));
                   client.ConcurrentAppend(fileName, true, buffer,counter,(int)stream.Length);

                 // Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",counter,counter+(int)stream.Length);
                   Array.Clear(buffer, counter,(int)stream.Length);

                  counter += (int)stream.Length+1;
                   if(counter==maxSize){
                      counter=0;
                   }
                   stream.Close();

           });
```

Comment: arrays are just ... arrays; they have no concept of partitioned locking; you can use a monitor on the array *object*, but anything else: you'd need to do yourself; what is it that you want to achieve with this locking?

Comment: What reason do you have for sharing the buffer?  It looks like each worker can just have their own buffer, removing any need for synchronization.

Comment: what i want is for example  thread 1 writes data to the array from counter 0 to x and then say , there is a context switch , i dont want any other thread to write data to array from index 0 to x -> that is i want to lock that part

Comment: @kchahat20 Have you considered [ArraySegment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: @PeterCsala it will increase the memory and the goal of my program is to keep memory as less as possible

Comment: @kchahat20 Can you please elaborate why do you think "it will increase memory"?